# Is it possible to setup my own DNS server which forwards to my OpenDNS configuration?

Tags: networking, security, dns, opendns

In my small office I currently have setup DD-WRT with OpenDNS as a website blocking methods, especially file sharing and social networking.
(https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenDNS)

However, when the employees take these laptops outside onsite, they connect their own hotspot and unblock all file sharing sites.
I cannot completely deny them outside internet access at they need to send emails back to the company regarding reports they got onsite.

Is it possible to setup my own DNS server, which forwards to my OpenDNS setup so that the same websites blocked in office are blocked over there?

Is such a setup possible?
Can I setup a DNS server which uses the same blocking as my OpenDNS setup?
Or a DNS server which forwards all requests to my OpenDNS setup?

Comment: Running your own DNS server which forwards to OpenDNS server is easy (that's what I have at home on VLAN for my children). But I think you are asking wrong question here and it should be: How do I control what sites my employees access on employer provided laptops while off-site? The answer might be: Cisco Anyconnect but this will likely cost you.

Answer (score 0):

what you're asking is going to be really hard to do. you don't have any control over your employee's hotspots (there is a way to prevent them from connecting to the hotspots but I'm pretty sure it's illegal). you also can't control which dns servers they use when they're not on your network. to summarize, there's no legal way to do what you're asking.